# How do you increase your combat effectiveness in Anima BF?

Tags: combat, anima-beyond-fantasy

I'm getting introduced into Anima BF. Right now my character has 65 Attack and 53 Dodge, and today when I had a fight I realized these values are amazingly low. Since the story is already commenced I can't change it back, plus I spent a lot of points into Ki abilities and secondary abilities too.

When I created my character I picked up Nodachi as my weapon because it can be used with 2H and 1H, and I picked 8 STR becaus my game master said that we would be adding +1 cara point every level up, so by level 3 I could already have 10 STR and use it 1H.

So, based on this thinking I picked up Iai Jutsu + Yuuse Batto Jutsu, but right now I'm not able to use it, so my only real ability right now is Fukuryuzan.

I don't know, generally I feel that I made a bad decision trying to focus on a level 3+ character instead of trying to evolve it over time.

So my question is this: How can I squeeze out the maximum from my character so I don't have to stress when rolling attacks? What can I do to try and actually win a battle the first 2 levels?

Here is a picture of my current character (in Spanish, if someone understands it. I can't provide it in English).

[image: My character sheet]

I can translate any part of the sheet, so feel free to ask and I'll update the information.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As much as I like Anima: Beyond Fantasy, this isn't really an answerable question as it currently stands; The Anima rules are flexible enough that there's many different ways to build an effective character. You've presumably realised the obvious "try and keep your attack and defence values at their maximums" advice; Could you explain why that's not working for you?

Comment: And have you spoken to your GM about your concerns? Some Anima character builds are a little tricky to make viable at low levels by RAW; For example, certain paths of magic only grant defensive and offensive spells at path levels that aren't easily available at level one. YOur GM might already expect a little imbalance early on.

Comment: Thanks Random. The reason I picked ambidex is because Im planning to use it one-handed and I want to be able to use it with any hands. I didnt know that flying would give me extras, I picked it up because I wanted to get to some positions that usually you cant jumping.

Comment: Somebody deleted my last comment, that was some how rude... I think it is a viable question even though it needs rewording. The question I think @AitorMartinGonzalez is asking is, what ways are there in Anima to get bonuses in combat? It is not a 'build character min/max' question, since the character is already there. It is what rules (as RAW) are there to help in combat? and I have provided an answer and I think that before deleting a helpful answer you should **at least** tell the person your post are deleting that you are doing so.

Comment: @Random Not having read your comment, I'm guessing it was deleted as obsolete once the OP had responded to it. This is normal. Comments hanging around and *not* getting deleted is relatively rare; As soon as they've served their purpose, they are removed so as to avoid clutter.

Comment: @Random Unfortunately, nearly all of Anima's rules focus around combat in some way. Summarising everything from the rules that could grant bonuses is kind of a big task - easily big enough to qualify for our "too broad" close reason. If Aitor Martin Gonzalez posts some more information about what would make a bonus better than another in their eyes (besides "being bigger," obviously), then we'll be automatically notified to re-examine it.

Comment: Actually I talked to the GM and I could re-do my character sheet and I've got a pretty decent character now. Also I think the question is really too broad, because Anima supports so many skills and feats to increase your combat effectiveness that there is no point on updating the question.